# console.log(err.message); & console.log(err[0].message);

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, error-handling, console.log

When using the Twitter API, if all is well then using `err[0].message` will return `You have already ___ed this tweet.`, however if a HTTP Status Code comes through, say due to rate limiting, then output will become `TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined` which can cause the script to stop on fail.

This can be resolved by changing `err[0].message` to `err.message`, however, if all is well it will return `undefined` instead of `You have already ____ed this tweet.`.

Snippet when using `err.message`:

```
T.post('statuses/retweet', id, function(err, response){
    // log failures
    if(err){
      console.log(err.message);
```

Output when rate limited:

```
HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
```

Output when not rate limited:

```
undefined
```

Snippet when using `err[0].message`:

```
T.post('statuses/retweet', id, function(err, response){
    // log failures
    if(err){
      console.log(err.message);
```

Output when rate limited:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

Output when not rate limited:

```
You have already retweeted this tweet.
```

So what would be the best way to handle this to ensure both can log properly without causing an error or being unclear on output?

Comment: You can check if `err` is an array or if `err.message` exists and then log the appropriate thing.

Comment: How might I separate the 2, though, so neither interfere with each other based on the condition?

That's where I'm having trouble.

Comment: Something like `if (err[0]) { console.log(err[0].message } else { console.log(err.message) }` - probably not exactly like this but that sort of thing.

Comment: I kind of overlooked this, I suppose frustration can be attributed. Thanks so much, this pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no errors, `err` will be `undefined`

If rate limiting occurs, `err` will be `HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests`

If some other error occurs, `err` will be an array.

You can check for the `err` type to handle all the scenarios.

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');

T.post('statuses/retweet', id, function (err, response) {

  if (err) {
    if (_.isArray(err)) {
      // handles You have already ___ed this tweet.
      console.log(err[0].message);
    } else {
      // this takes care of HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Pretty much what I went with, thanks! I was questioning if isArray would be appropriate for this.